# How to setup an Yocto recipe to build from a local git source?

Tags: git, cmake, yocto, bitbake, yocto-recipe

Hej

I am playing a bit around with Yocto, a Raspberry Pi and some code I have written. I want to build by Yocto an image including the program I have written. I like to know how to setup the fetcher to fetch from a local git repo.

My setup is simple. The code is in the directory:

```
/home/user/git/myTest
```

I linked the directory into the directory which contains the recipe of my Yocto meta-layer. The directory is:

```
/home/user/poky/meta-test/myApp/myTest
```

Because it is a local git repo, it contains the ".git" folder.

```
/home/user/git/myTest/.git
```

Inside the directory there are many files:

```
/home/user/git/myTest/CMakeLists.txt
/home/user/git/myTest/src/main.cpp
/home/user/git/myTest/src/...
```

I like to know how to setup my recipe to use the git fetcher:

```
SUMMARY = "test"
SECTION = "app"
LICENSE = "CLOSED"

inherit cmake

SRCREV = "${AUTOREV}"

SRC_URI = "git://.git"

S = "${WORKDIR}/git"
```

I did check the Yocto/Bitbake documentation. But I did not find an example suited to do it.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

GIT Fetcher in `bitbake` [supports different protocols](https://www.yoctoproject.org/docs/1.6/bitbake-user-manual/bitbake-user-manual.html#git-fetcher) but with rather peculiar and non-standard syntax. In your case it should be something like

```
SRC_URI = "git:///home/user/git/myTest/;protocol=file"
```

Comment: This non-standard syntax had me really confused when trying `SRC_URI = "file:///home/user/git/myTest/;protocol=file"`.

Comment: But I guess it makes sense now after reading `4.3.6. Other Fetchers` in the documentation.  Thanks!

Comment: All other programs (`npm` or `pip` for example) use different syntax like `git+https://gitlab.com/…` so they can easily switch both "fetcher" (VCS) and the protocol. That's why I complain about peculiar and non-standard syntax.

Answer (score -4):

Like below, you can access from local,

SRC_URI = "git:///home/path.git; file:defconfig"

It will access the respective local file.