# How to use a local git server URL in recipe?

Tags: yocto

I tried to use local git server URL as the SRC_URL, but error occurred during compilation. And I already tested this URL by git clone command. Does anyone know how to fix this issue?

Recipe:

```
KERNEL_SRC ?= "localhost:/opt/git/linux-fmc-imx_4.14.git;protocol=https"
SRC_URI = "${KERNEL_SRC};branch=${SRCBRANCH}"
```

Error message:

```
Error executing a python function in <code>:--:--:--
...
The URL: 'localhost:/opt/git/linux-fmc-imx_4.14.git;protocol=http;branch=imx_4.14.98_2.0.0_ga' is invalid and cannot be interpreted
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to setup an Yocto recipe to build from a local git source?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49535881/how-to-setup-an-yocto-recipe-to-build-from-a-local-git-source)

Comment: Did you try using `ssh` protocol instead of `https`?

Comment: Yes, I used ssh protocol

Comment: Please, have a look at the SRC_URI variable syntax here -> https://www.yoctoproject.org/docs/1.8/ref-manual/ref-manual.html#var-SRC_URI The localhost keyword is not in the list, i suggest you try SRC_URI = "git:///opt/git/linux-fmc-imx_4.14.git;protocol=https;branch=${SRCBRANCH}"