# How to modify a yocto recipe to fetch source files from a local folder instead from official GitHub repository?

Tags: git, yocto, yocto-recipe

### Installation on Pillow in the yocto linux distribution

I have installed the **Pillow** Python Library in my yocto-based distribution by the following recipe:

```
meta-openembedded/meta-python/recipes-devtools/python/python3-pillow_6.2.1.bb
```

and by adding the following instruction to `my_image_recipe.bb`:

```
IMAGE_INSTALL += "python3-pillow"
```

By the `bitbake` compilation of `my_image_recipe.bb`, Pillow has been  installed in the Linux distribution.

### Modify SRC_URI to fetch source from local directory

What I need is to create a `python3-pillow_%.bbappend` file to modify the value of the `SRC_URI` variable of the Pillow recipe. In the original recipe the value of that variable is:

```
SRC_URI = "git://github.com/python-pillow/Pillow.git;branch=6.2.x \
           file://0001-support-cross-compiling.patch \
           file://0001-explicitly-set-compile-options.patch \
"
```

With this value of `SRC_URI`,  when I execute the command:

```
> bitbake python3-pillow
```

the source tree of Pillow is downloaded from the **GitHub repository** pointed by the URI value assigned to `SRC_URI`. As we can see above, the URL used for the download is:

```
git://github.com/python-pillow/Pillow.git;branch=6.2.x
```

By the fetching process the source files are saved in one my local folder called `downloads`. This folder is the target of all the downloads executed by the image build process.

After the image creation `downloads` contains the Pillow source tree in the following sub-folder:

```
downloads/git2/github.com.python-pillow.Pillow.git/
```

### My question

I would like to copy the source tree downloaded into the path `downloads/git2/github.com.python-pillow.Pillow.git/` in a different folder called `my-downloads` and modify the `SRC_URI` variable as followed:

```
SRC_URI = "file:///path/to/my-downloads/... \  # <---??? What do I have to write in this assignment exactly???
           file://0001-support-cross-compiling.patch \
           file://0001-explicitly-set-compile-options.patch \
"
```

In this way when I'll compile Pillow an other time, `bitbake` will take Pillow source tree  from `my-downloads` and not from GitHub.

What exactly do I have to assign to `SRC_URI` in order for `bitbake` to find Pillow sources in my local folder `my-downloads`?

---

I have tried with the solution proposed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49535881/how-to-setup-an-yocto-recipe-to-build-from-a-local-git-source) but it doesn't work in my context may be because I don't get sources from a local git repository, but directly from filesystem.

Comment: file:///path/to/my-downloads/;protocol=file

Comment: Thanks. I'll try as soon as possible..

Comment: keep me updated

Comment: @void_brain Your suggestion doesn't solve my problem. I get an error when it is applied the patch `0001-support-cross-compiling.patch`. I think that I can't manage a  source tree downloaded from GitHub as a filesystem source tree. May be I need a local Git repository. If you have other tips I will appreciate them.

Comment: @void_brain I have solved the problem; the error in your comment is the use of `file://` instead of `git://`. It is necessary to specify the GIT Fetcher to `bitbake`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the source of Pillow from filesystem, instead from GitHub site,  I had to create the file `python3-pillow_%.bbappend`, with the following assignment:

```
SRC_URI = "git:///file:///path/to/my-downloads/github.com.python-pillow.Pillow.git;branch=6.2.x;protocol=file \
           file://0001-support-cross-compiling.patch \
           file://0001-explicitly-set-compile-options.patch \
"
```

#### Parameters `protocol` and `branch` for the GIT Fetcher

As explained in the [Bitbake User Manual](https://docs.yoctoproject.org/1.6/bitbake-user-manual/bitbake-user-manual.html#git-fetcher) to solve the problem showed in the question the most important concepts to know are:

- set the `GIT Fetcher` by `git://`
- set the parameter `protocol=file` for the `GIT Fetcher`
- set the parameter `branch=6.2.x` for the `GIT Fetcher`

By this way the code is fetched from filesystem and not from GitHub site.

#### Note

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49535881/how-to-setup-an-yocto-recipe-to-build-from-a-local-git-source) is useful, but for my problem in it is missed the parameter `branch` so when I tried its solution, it didn't perfectly answer my question.